Why does adding .AsQueryable() and .AsNoTracking() seem to work for filtering related entities in Entity Framework Core?
I need to filter related entities while including them in the query.
Each Order has a Customer, and multiple OrderItems, and each OrderItem has a Product. I want to include OrderItems that either match a specified product category or a default category.
Here's the code I tried:
var orders = await _context.Orders
    .AsQueryable()
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(order => order.CustomerId == customerId)
    .Include(order => order.Customer)
    .Include(order => order.OrderItems)
    .ThenInclude(oi => oi.Product.Where(p => p.Category.ToUpper() == category || p.Category == DefaultCategory))
    .ToListAsync();

Surprisingly, this code seems to work, but I am aware that Include and ThenInclude do not directly support filtering with Where clauses. I am also unsure why adding .AsQueryable() and .AsNoTracking() appears to resolve the issue.
Why does adding .AsQueryable() and .AsNoTracking() seem to work in this case?

EF Core 8 does support filtered includes. This has nothing to do with AsQueryable and AsNoTracking. The real problem is that p.Category.ToUpper() that prevents the use of indexes. If your database has a case-insensitive collation you don't need ToUpper() at all. SQL Server databases typically use case-insensitive collations. In other databases you should create indexes with a case-insensitive collation if you want to avoid table scans

Filtered Includes are available since EF Core 5. What's the real problem here? Have you already loaded the related products perhaps? The docs warn about this exact case: During navigation fixup, the DbContext will find the related Product objects in memory and connect them to OrderItem. AsNoTracking() prevents using the tracked, ie cached objects. That doesn't mean there's no filtered include.

Is _context a singleton perhaps? What kind of application are you building? ASP.NET Core MVC, Web API and Razor Pages applications create a separate DbContext instance per request which means you'd have to explicitly load all Products in the same request. In desktop and Blazor Server applications you have to explicitly control the lifetime of the DbContext, possibly using a DbContextFactory, otherwise you can end up with worse problems than unexpected Includes. You can end up persisting changes made by a different operation that you thought were discarded

As mentioned in answer below, if you do not use AsNoTracking and detail items already tracked, Include filter will be not applied to already tracked items.

.AsQueryable() should have no impact on what sql is generated. It's merely a cast operation to ensure that the return type is IQueryable.
.AsNoTracking() also shouldn't have any impact. Unless you have other related entities that have already been tracked by this context. As tracking entities will link all navigation properties with any other entity that has already been tracked.
You can filter any .Include() or .ThenInclude(). While you can .Include() a single navigation multiple times, you can't apply multiple different filters to the same navigation property.
